# Combining videos and recording sound over them

Tags: windows, video, audio, recording, video-editing

This is the idea: I want to have a video where I appear twice. With pictures this is easy: you take two pictures of yourself without moving the camera, once in each corner of the room, and then combine half and half with MS Paint. What free Windows program can do this with videos?

Also, I later want to record some more sound over it. Will that same program allow me to do that, or do I need something else?

Answer (score 1):

[**Avisynth**](http://www.avisynth.org/) allows you to do this things. I love it (for example, I did [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqOptUyRBPs) myself with it, both the splitting and the merge) but it's not user friendly, more apt for programmers.

Comment: @leonbloy.. That is a great clip... well done, for both the guitar playing and the AviSynth :) ... I think AviSynth is absolutely fantastic...it can do almost anything you can think of... by the way, how did you do all the little animals an bricks and blocks of wood etc.. there must be some transparency/overlay feature I don't know about...

Comment: Thanks. That was done with the `Overlay` function, playing with the `mask` option. I first defined a mask using `mimask=ColorKeyMask(movie.ConvertToRGB(),$b67739,26).ShowAlpha())` There is an example here http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Overlay

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) can help you.

> Audacity® is free, open source software for recording and editing sounds. It is available for Mac OS X, Microsoft Windows, GNU/Linux, and other operating systems.

[image]

Comment: You mean with the sound recording part? How can I use it to record sound over a video?

Comment: @Javier: audacity just records the sound; you'll need video editing software to add that sound into your video.

Comment: @quack: Right, I realized that a while after I posted my comment.

Comment: @javier: good good.  (you know you can delete (and edit) your comments, right?)  still, i'd leave the first two comments for the benefit of other readers that may have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Movie Maker will allow you to add audio on top of the video, but I'm not sure if it can overlay two videos. Generally speaking you are looking for [video editing software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_editing_software).

Comment: there are many questions on Super User about good video editing applications; see for example http://superuser.com/questions/28357/what-is-the-easiest-video-editing-program-to-use-on-windows or http://superuser.com/questions/87299/video-editing-software-for-windows-7